# mySQL find duplicates in table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: users and orders.

Sometimes I see users that are subscribed twice with different email but same first name, last name and VAT number.
I would like to select all users that have registered twice and both account have at least one order.
Then I want to see the detail for both accounts.

If I do something like

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, VAT, count(distinct o.id)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
WHERE 1=1
AND o.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, VAT
HAVING count(distinct u.id) > 1
```

I can select double accounts with orders but I can only see the sum of orders in both account. Instead I would like to see two lines for each one of them and see how many orders each line has, and possibly the id of each account

So:

| first name | last name | vat | id | orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robert | Smith | 11111 | id1 | 5 |
| Robert | Smith | 11111 | id2 | 3 |

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: @Akina 8.0.18-google

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables. Edit your query and add table alias to **each** column. Specify what table is `id` column of desired output taken from (users?).

Comment: Try Partition by firstname,lastname,vat

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT first_name, last_name, VAT, id,
           COUNT(DISTINCT id) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name, VAT) cnt
    FROM users
)
SELECT cte.first_name, cte.last_name, cte.VAT, cte.id, COUNT(*) orders
FROM cte
JOIN orders o ON cte.id = o.user_id
WHERE cte.cnt > 1
GROUP BY cte.first_name, cte.last_name, cte.VAT, cte.id
ORDER BY cte.first_name, cte.last_name, cte.VAT, cte.id
```